# Copying file from host during Docker build process to minimise image size

Tags: docker

I am creating a container image which has two large (10GB) applications installed.  I am currently using:

```
COPY <installer.file> <dest>

RUN <install application> \
   && rm <application installer file>
```

However, I am under the impression that if I were able to do the following:

```
RUN cp <installer files from host> \
   && <install application> \
   && rm <application installer file>
```

My image file would be significantly smaller.  (To clarify, this would remove the layer which had the installer file in it.)

I'm aware that volumes are not mounted until the end of the build process - is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Indeed you can delete the installation file after app is installed, but from your OP I understand that the large disk amount is occupied by application itself and not the installation file. If I am wrong, edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: Edited.  The issue is that I'm trying to reduce the image size by removing the layer which has the installer file in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a multi-stage build:

```
FROM some_image as build

COPY <installer.file> <dest>

RUN <install application> \
   && rm <application installer file>

FROM some_image

COPY --from=build / /
```

This way your final image contains only the installed applications and no intermediary layers.

In the last line you can also copy only this folders where the application was actually installed.

Comment: I guess I want to do

```FROM build
RUN whatever``` - will that just remove past layers?

Comment: I noticed this misconception in your first post as well but now I will clarify: nothing removes old layers. You can only prevent them from being persisted. And that is what you do by putting many commands on 1 line with a delete command as last command. After each line in Dockerfile a new layer is created and that will not be deleted unless you delete the line in Dockerfile and rebuild. (not really deleted but ignored). So my solution does not remove layers but starts from a clean situation and only creates 1 layer (the one where it copies from the build stage).

Comment: So I'm really stuck with a 38GB image for a file system half the size?  That seems like a genuine problem to be fixed.

Comment: You tried my solution and the image is still that big? Can you run "docker image history" and send the result?

Comment: Yes, I tried the solution: dockerfile looks like this:
```FROM python:2.7 as builder
...
FROM builder
CMD source blah.sh
```
Size of image is 43GB. Output of image history (times and commands removed):
```
x   0B                  
y   431kB               
z   413MB               
x   1.42kB              
x   12.3GB              
x       0B                  
x                 0B                  
x  13.1GB              
x 16.5GB
```

Comment: I saw nw the error: the second from is NOT from "build" but from the same image as the first FROM. Ex: if the first from is FROM windows then the second one should also be FROM windows. What you are doing is just cancelling all the beauty of multistage builds. Can you retry?

Comment: Thanks Mihai... but I need it to include the filesystem I've just built in "builder".

Comment: And that is exactly what "COPY --from=build / /" is doing: copy all the files from the build stage into the new stage, but ignoring the intermediate layers.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will lose the build history i.e. `docker history <image>` will show only one layer for the image.

Assuming I have a large installer script, **sdk.sh** in the build context, it can be run during the container build without copying it into the container with the following command in the Docker file:

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=sdk.sh,readonly,source=sdk.sh bash sdk.sh
```

The command at the end can be any executable command that uses **sdk.sh**.

The large installer file is still copied to the docker daemon as part of the build context, but it will not be copied into the final image, and will therefore not bloat the image with its hidden presence. The image build history is also preserved.